# How can I adjust the dimensions of a QR Code in C# using MessagingToolkit?

Tags: c#, qr-code

I am having my function for generating QR codes:

```
private string PrintLabel1(int id)
{
    string code = Read(id);
    string companyName = "MyCompanyName";
    string combinedPath = string.Format("{0} | {1}", code, companyName);
    string folderPath = "C:\\Labels";

    if (!Directory.Exists(folderPath))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(folderPath);
    }

    string qrCodeFilePath = Path.Combine(folderPath, "label.png");

    MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder();

    qrCodeEncoder.QRCodeEncodeMode = MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder.ENCODE_MODE.BYTE;
    qrCodeEncoder.QRCodeScale = 6;
    qrCodeEncoder.QRCodeVersion = 10;
    qrCodeEncoder.QRCodeErrorCorrect = MessagingToolkit.QRCode.Codec.QRCodeEncoder.ERROR_CORRECTION.L;

    Bitmap qrCodeBitmap = qrCodeEncoder.Encode(combinedPath);

    int marginSize = 20;
    Bitmap qrCodeBitmapWithMargin = new Bitmap(qrCodeBitmap.Width + 2 * marginSize, qrCodeBitmap.Height + 3 * marginSize);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(qrCodeBitmapWithMargin))
    {
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.White, 0, 0, qrCodeBitmapWithMargin.Width, qrCodeBitmapWithMargin.Height);
        g.DrawImage(qrCodeBitmap, marginSize, marginSize);

        string additionalText = Read(id);
        System.Drawing.Font font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 12);
        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
        float textWidth = g.MeasureString(additionalText, font).Width;
        g.DrawString(additionalText, font, brush, (qrCodeBitmapWithMargin.Width - textWidth) / 2, qrCodeBitmapWithMargin.Height - marginSize);
    }

    qrCodeBitmapWithMargin.Save(qrCodeFilePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "image/png";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=label.png");
    Response.TransmitFile(qrCodeFilePath);
    Response.End();

    return code;
}
```

However, my company is using some sort of different label printer and I need to adjust size of the generated QR code to 2,54cm x 5,4cm. Those are custom dimensions, and I am having some sort of trouble because whenever I try to change dimensions the whole QR code is being rescaled and it's hard to read/scan. How do I do that?